# xCode Swift file grayed out with red text

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swift3, storyboard

I can't build my app successfully. I think this is the issue. What does grayed out red text mean? I cloned the project from a new branch on github created by a team member.

BUILD ERROR:

```
Command 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: that means the reference of these files are removed from project.

Comment: These classes seems like missing from your project, Add these classes again

Comment: check my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

`Command` + `Shift` + `K` and `Run` it again.

Comment: This worked for me. Don't know why this was getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

Note - if these files are required then do below otherwise delete them from your project

1) Right click on your project. and click on Add Files to...

[image]

2) It will open a window where you can see the deleted file just select them and click on Add button.

Comment: I clicked add file but I dont see the missing files

Answer (score 0):

You can add them again by clicking on addFiles
[image]

Comment: I clicked add file but I dont see the missing files